# OCaml Hashtbl/0.t and Hashtbl/-1.t

Tags: ocaml, hashtable

I am quite new to OCaml, so I am not sure what the following error message means (specifically the `/0` and the `/-1`):

```
Error: This expression has type (string, string) Hashtbl/0.t
       but an expression was expected of type ('a, 'b) Hashtbl/-1.t
```

I am passing a `Hashtbl.t` into `Hashtbl.find` and this error shows up. I am unclear as to how the `/0` and `/-1` came in, and what they actually mean.

Here's a minimal working example to demonstrate my issue:

```
open Core_kernel.Std

let file_to_hashtbl filename =
  let sexp_to_hashtbl_str = Sexplib.Conv.hashtbl_of_sexp
      string_of_sexp string_of_sexp
  in In_channel.with_file
    filename ~f:(fun ch -> (Sexp.input_sexp ch |> sexp_to_hashtbl_str))

let ht = file_to_hashtbl "test"

let t1_val = match Hashtbl.find ht "t1" with
  | Some v -> v
  | None -> assert false

let () = print_endline t1_val
```

Comment: I'm sure you're using the interpreter, see my answer ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's show you an example :

If I write

```
type t = A;;
let x = A;;
type t = B;;
let y = B;;
x = y;;
Error: This expression has type t/1561 but an expression was expected of type
     t/1558
```

This is because in the interpreter you can declare multiple types with the same name and associate values to these types. But here, as you can see, `x` and `y` are not of the same type but both the types are named `t` so the interpreter tries to tell you the types are both named `t` but are not the same.

**[Compilation]**

If I wanted to compile this, I would have to declare

**typea.ml**

```
type t = A
let x = A
```

**typeb.ml**

```
type t = B
let y = B
```

**main.ml**

```
open Typea
open Typeb

x = y
```

If I compile this I will have

```
Error: This expression has type Typeb.t
   but an expression was expected of type Typea.t
```

What lesson should you learn from this ? ***Stop interpreting, compile !***

Now that I managed to compile your file, I got an error too but much more explicit :

```
 Error: This expression has type (string, string) Hashtbl.t
   but an expression was expected of type
     ('a, 'b) Core_kernel.Std.Hashtbl.t =
       ('a, 'b) Core_kernel.Core_hashtbl.t
```

**[Explanation and correction]**

Since I'm too nice, here is your file corrected :

```
let file_to_hashtbl filename =
  (* open the namespace only where needed *)
  let open Core_kernel.Std in
  let sexp_to_hashtbl_str = Sexplib.Conv.hashtbl_of_sexp
                              string_of_sexp string_of_sexp
  in In_channel.with_file
       filename ~f:(fun ch -> (Sexp.input_sexp ch |> sexp_to_hashtbl_str));;

let ht = file_to_hashtbl "test"

let t1_val = 
  try
    Hashtbl.find ht "t1" 
  with Not_found -> assert false

let () = print_endline t1_val
```

Your error was that you opened `Core_kernel.Std` as a global namespace so when you wrote `Hashtbl.find` it looked first in `Core_kernel.Std` and not in the standard library.

What I did is open `Core_kernel.Std` in the function that needs it, not in the whole file (so it's a local namespace) (*a good habit to take*).

So, as you can see, the problem was that you had two definition of the type `Hashtbl.t` (one in `Core_kernel.Std` and one in the standard library) and OCaml ain't no fool, boy, he knows when you're wrong but he is hard to understand since he only speak for those who can hear. :-D

P.S. : You had an error in your `Hashtbl.find` because it doesn't return an option but the found value or raise a `Not_found` exception if no value was found. I corrected it too. ;-)

Comment: Well, I was not interpreting the code, but was compiling, so I'm not sure if the first part of your answer applies, but the second part makes sense. I realized that it must be due to some name clash, but didn't realize it was due to the opening of the namespace. Thanks for pointing that out (and the PS correction as well). Now I'll just have to figure out how to make my error messages show up better (like yours :D )

Comment: BTW, might I suggest editing your answer and removing the "interpreted" part? I am not sure it is useful to anyone else who might chance upon the same issues as I did, and find this question. However, it is your call on how to edit. Cheers!

Comment: I will do it. What's your compiler ?

Comment: That's strange because I installed several OCaml compilers and I always have a clear answer not like yours.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, it is just a matter of missing semi-columns, the foloowing code compiles :

```
open Core_kernel.Std;;

let file_to_hashtbl filename =
  let sexp_to_hashtbl_str = Sexplib.Conv.hashtbl_of_sexp
      string_of_sexp string_of_sexp
  in In_channel.with_file
    filename ~f:(fun ch -> (Sexp.input_sexp ch |> sexp_to_hashtbl_str));;

let ht = file_to_hashtbl "test"

let t1_val = match Hashtbl.find ht "t1" with
  | Some v -> v
  | None -> assert false

let () = print_endline t1_val
```

But, I do not know how to interpret the error message neither.

Comment: Adding `;;` at the end of a function will _never_ make the typing go from wrong to correct...